# Systemd service that stops if dependency stops, but not when it restarts

Tags: systemd

Is it possible to a define systemd service that will stop if its dependency stops (or crashes), but will keep running uninterrupted if its dependency restarts?

The closest I got is with `BindTo` declaration, but that also stops my service if the dependency restarts.

---

Clarification: If the dependency goes away for good (stopped, failed), I want my service stopped. If the dependency goes away for short time (restarted), I want my service uninterrupted.

Comment: Did you check `Requires`? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388586/systemd-requires-vs-wants

Comment: I tried. Even `Requires` restarts my service if the dependency restarts.

Comment: Logically, If service 'X' depends on 'Y' then if 'Y' not available for any amount of time "including restart", 'X' should stop, unless 'X' source code handle the case by waiting for 'Y' or fail over to another instance of 'Y'.

Comment: Some services can restart without interrupting what they do. For example the file descriptors provided by `systemd-logind` remain valid if the service restarts, but not if it stops.

Comment: logically remain valid how? it seems there is `defined timeout value`, or `hold all processing and keep trying till dependency is up`. Also some OS services have many services depending on it.

Comment: For example `systemd-logind` gives you file descriptors for input devices. When you switch sessions, it uses EVIOCREVOKE to revoke access to mute them a. If `systemd-logind` is restarted, it will remember those file descriptor and keep managing them after restart. If it is stopped, it will revoke them all.

Comment: In your example, Are you sure the logic you described fully happened within systemd? I think the part `remember those file descriptor` is handled in the code it self.

Comment: Well that's just the behavior of the `systemd-logind` service - just example that restart can be different than stop&start. But my question is general - how to react to stop and ignore restart of a dependency.